# com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[docSearch]

Tags: java, webclient, htmlunit

I am trying to get to the `docSearch` form of the https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp web page using the latest HTMLUnit release (2.37.0). As you can see using Firefox's DOM Inspector, there is such a form

```java
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
    public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("handleRefresh");
    }
});
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(100000);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager().waitForJobs(1000000);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000000);
HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("docSearch");
```

The last line of the above code gives me the following exception:

> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[docSearch]

Any tips on what I can try in my code to get to the `docSearch` form ? 
Do you believe this is a problem with HTMLUnit itself? Should I file this as an issue on HTMLUnit's GitHub site?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208048/discussion-on-question-by-gods-gift-to-java-com-gargoylesoftware-htmlunit-eleme).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really desperate, usually it is more helpful to try to understand what is going on than copy every snippet you can find into you code and hope this will help.

A good starting point is to understand how the page is working. Use a good web proxy like Charles (or Fiddler) to monitor what happens when you open the page with your browser. Sadly I cannot open your url because my browser reports server not found. Because of this the rest of this answer is more of a guess.

The next step is to create your web client and try to live with the default settings.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

With this two lines your client is ready.
At least you RefreshHandler setup completely breaks the handling of refresh cases.

Next step is to check the output after you got the page and compare with your browser/web proxy session.

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp");
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

No you can check if the form is there (in the output) or not. If not you have to figure out with the proxy if there is any  kind of js based background reloading. Usual you will see the requests in your proxy output.

To wait for this you can call something like

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(100_000);
```

Sometimes these backround jobs are replacing the content of the current window. To take care of this it is a good idea to get the current page content from the window before dumping.

```
page = page.getEnclosingWindow(getEnclosedPage());
System.out.println(page.asXML());
```

Hope that clarifies it a bit. If you need more help i need to be able to access the page myself. Otherwise it is only guessing.

Comment: I tried the following code: `WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_68);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());   
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000000);        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp");
     page =  (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
System.out.println(page.asXml());` and there is no docSearch in the printout.

Comment: waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore is not an option, you have to call it AFTER getPage and BEFORE getEnclosingWindow

Comment: Noted RBRi. The page.asXtm() I posted in the comments on top of this page was after I put the waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore after getPage and before getEnclosingWindow. Also, the parameter I used for waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore to get that page.asXtm() is 10000000 (ten million), not 1000000 (one million), just to make sure the issue is not not waiting long enough.

Comment: I have filed the issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

Have spend some time on this to build a complete sample. The page is only available from the us - i had to set up a vpn to access the page. The sample contains some hints; hope that helps.

```
final String url = "https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    // webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

    // open the url, this will do a redirect to the login page
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    // System.out.println(page.asXml());
    // System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    // click the Public User Login
    for (DomElement elem : page.getElementById("middle_left").getElementsByTagName("input")) {
        if (elem instanceof HtmlSubmitInput
                && "Login".equals(((HtmlSubmitInput) elem).getValueAttribute())) {
            page = elem.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(page.asXml());
    // System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    // search by owner name
    HtmlInput ownerInput = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("TaxAOwnerIDSearchString");
    ownerInput.type("Trump");
    // click submit
    for (DomElement elem : page.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
        if (elem instanceof HtmlSubmitInput) {
            page = elem.click();
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(page.asXml());
    // System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    System.out.println(page.asText());
```

Comment: That did work. It got me to the next page that I wanted. Still have to go another page further to get to the page I really want, but the roadblock I reported was lifted. Thanks. I am still a little confused though. Your code seems to have logged into something. That seems to jibe with one of GamingFelix's suggestions. Why was that necessary, since no logging is needed when you go to https://eagletw.mohavecounty.us/treasurer/treasurerweb/search.jsp using Firefox. I am asking out of curiosity, and to reduce risk I run into a similar roadblock when trying to get to next page in HtmlUnit browsing.